# How to reorder nested fields in table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two Google BigQuery tables with same data structure but different field ordering:

```
+- table1: record             
|  +- FIELD: record (repeated)    
|  |  |- FIELD.blue: string
|  |  |- FIELD.yellow: integer         
+- table2: record                
|  +- FIELD: record (repeated)    
|  |  |- FIELD.yellow: integer         
|  |  |- FIELD.blue: string
```

I need to concatenate both tables:

```
select * from `table1` 
union all 
select * from `table2`
```

but I get the following error:

```
Column 5 in UNION ALL has incompatible types
```

Is there a way to reorder the nested fields so I can union both tables or is there another method to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could do - use `REPLACE` to regenerate the nested object in one table while querying:

```
WITH ta AS (SELECT 'x' id
  , [STRUCT('a' AS a, 3 AS b)] st) ,
tb AS (SELECT 'y' id
  , [STRUCT(1 AS b, 'b' AS a)] st)

SELECT * 
FROM ta
UNION ALL 
SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a,b)) FROM UNNEST(st)) AS st) 
FROM tb
```